# Can there be a more prominent link to the meta sites from the main sites?

Tags: feature-request, meta

I was just looking at a post on money.SE and wanted to raise a meta post about it. I couldn't immediately see a link to the meta site and when I Ctrl-F'd "meta" in my browser window I got "Hot Meta Posts" sidebar and a link to the general Meta in the footer, and that was it.

I ended up clicking on one of the linked hot meta posts and then navigating up from there but a direct link would have been nice... maybe only for people with above a certain rep if you want to avoid noobs ending up there when they were aiming for the main site?

I have now seen the meta link at the top of the SE dropdown menu in the header bar, but as dynamic content that doesn't show up in a text search on the window.

Comment: Nah. I don't think it's really needed.

Comment: It is also under the help menu: **Meta** *Discuss the workings and policies of this site*

Comment: @rene, Cool, I didn't know that until now :-)

Comment: And under the Stack Exchange drop down in the upper left, if you're logged in, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I think there should be.

I don't see why we'd "hide" the existence of meta, and make people have to go looking for it, which assumes you know about it.

I don't think the link in the help menu is sufficient, as evidenced by the fact that at least me, a commenter, and the OP didn't think to look there for it.  In fact, I went "whoa, there's a help menu tucked away up there - I never noticed!"
This is because the prominent "place to look for help" is the yellow "how to ask" box.

I think there should be an always-visible link to meta in that box.

Comment: This is part of a [larger problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279661/usability-issues-for-first-time-stack-exchange-users-a-micro-study).  In short, *the top bar is invisible to new users,* and that bar is pretty much the gate-keeper to the entire Help system.